# How to change password of a user in WSO2 IS 5.9.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am integrating WSO2 IS with our node js backend and react js frontend and was successful in performing operatoins for login,sign up & api calls.

Please help me how i can change password of an existing user using any api of wso2 IS ?

Please help

Comment: May be this helps: https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2torial-changing-passwords-in-wso2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to change password in WSO2 Identity server. You can choose it based on your requirements.

**Option1**:

Admins can do force password reset for a user account. [Please refer to this document](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/forced-password-reset/) for configuring the admin forced password reset.
UserProfileMgtService (a soap service) is used for admin forced password reset. Once the admin invoked the soap service, an email link will be sent to the user's email address and user can change the password by clicking on the verification email/OTP.

**Option2:**

You can do force password reset via scim patch operation also. [Refer to this document for further details about scim patch operation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/using-the-scim-2.0-rest-apis/#patch-update-me).

- Do the required configuration for force password reset. [Refer to this document for admin forced password recovery](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/forced-password-reset/)
- [Add a SCIM 2 schema extension](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/get-started/provisioning-architecture/#extensible-scim-user-schemas) for force password reset.
- Choose either
  'Enable Password Reset via Recovery Email' or 'Enable Password Reset
  via OTP'
- Try SCIM2 patch operation to enable force password reset for
  a user

> curl -v -k --user admin:admin --header
>   "Content-Type:application/json"
>   'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/[scim_user_id]' -X PATCH -d
>   '{"schemas": 
>   ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp","urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"],"Operations":
>   [{"op": "add","value":
>   {"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":
>   {"forcePasswordReset": true} }}]}

**Option3:**

You can use **UserAdmin** soap service to update the user password. [Please refer to the soap service here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/master/components/user-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui/src/main/resources/UserAdmin.wsdl). In WSO2 dashboard also, this admin service is used. [You can use this soap services as rest call also](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/10/article-exposing-wso2-identity-server-admin-services-the-rest-way/#step2). This will directly change the user's password without sending any email notification or verification.

**Option4 :**

If you need password recovery, in case of user forgot the password, the user can recover the password via email notification or using challenge questions. [Please refer to this document to configure the password recovery feature](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/password-recovery/)

Comment: There is no example using this SCIM API. It would be good if we have a step by step. Calling the API and so forth.